# how to read RINEX file in java

Tags: javascript, java

i am trying to read a RINEX file using java. what i can come up with is shown in the code below. i only managed to read the header part of the rinex file. but since rinex file is thousands of line i dont think i can read all of it using the method i used in the code below.
Is there another way to read the rinex file.

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gnssproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;

/**
 *
 * @author robel
 */
public class readRinexNavAll {

    private static Scanner x;

    int ieph;
    int sv;
    int MAX_CHAR = 100;
    char[] str = new char[MAX_CHAR];
    String[] tmp = new String[20];

    Calendar t;
    Calendar g;
    Calendar g0;
    double dt;

    int flags = 0x0;

    public static void open() {

        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("brdc3540.14n"));
            System.out.println("file found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }

    }

    public static void readFile() {

        while (x.hasNext()) {

            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();
            String d = x.next();
            String e = x.next();
            String f = x.next();
            String g = x.next();
            String h = x.next();
            String i = x.next();

            String j = x.next();
            String k = x.next();
            String l = x.next();
            String m = x.next();
            String n = x.next();
            String o = x.next();
            String p = x.next();
            String q = x.next();
            String r = x.next();

            String s = x.next();
            String t = x.next();
            String u = x.next();
            String v = x.next();
            String w = x.next();
            String xx = x.next();
            String y = x.next();
            String z = x.next();

            String aa = x.next();
            String bb = x.next();
            String cc = x.next();
            String dd = x.next();
            String ee = x.next();
            String ff = x.next();
            String gg = x.next();
            String hh = x.next();

            String ii = x.next();
            String jj = x.next();
            String kk = x.next();
            String ll = x.next();
            String mm = x.next();
            String nn = x.next();
            String oo = x.next();
            String pp = x.next();
            String qq = x.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i);

            //Read header lines
            if ("NAVIGATION".equals(b)) {
                System.out.println("correct");
                //   tmp[] = b;

            } else {
                System.out.println("not the same");
            }

            ////////////////////// ION ALPHA ///////////////////////
            System.out.println("ION ALPHA");
            char charArray[] = new char[15];

            y.getChars(0, 10, charArray, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray, 10);

            for (char character : charArray) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char alpha0;
                alpha0 = character;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(alpha0);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray1[] = new char[15];

            z.getChars(0, 10, charArray1, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray1, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray1) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char alpha1;
                alpha1 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(alpha1);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray2[] = new char[15];

            aa.getChars(0, 11, charArray2, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray2, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray2) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char alpha2;
                alpha2 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(alpha2);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray3[] = new char[15];

            bb.getChars(0, 10, charArray3, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray3, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray3) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char alpha3;
                alpha3 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(alpha3);

            }
            System.out.println();

            ////////////////////// ION BETA ///////////////////////
            System.out.println("ION BETA");
            char charArray4[] = new char[15];

            ee.getChars(0, 10, charArray4, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray4, 10);

            for (char character : charArray4) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char beta0;
                beta0 = character;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(beta0);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray5[] = new char[15];

            ff.getChars(0, 11, charArray5, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray5, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray5) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char beta1;
                beta1 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(beta1);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray6[] = new char[15];

            gg.getChars(0, 11, charArray6, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray6, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray6) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char beta2;
                beta2 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(beta2);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray7[] = new char[15];

            hh.getChars(0, 10, charArray7, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray7, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray7) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char beta3;
                beta3 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(beta3);

            }
            System.out.println();

            ////////////////////// DELTA UTC ///////////////////////
            System.out.println("DELTA UTC");
            char charArray8[] = new char[20];

            kk.getChars(0, 18, charArray8, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray8, 0);

            for (char character : charArray8) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char A0;
                A0 = character;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(A0);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray9[] = new char[20];

            ll.getChars(0, 18, charArray9, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray9, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray9) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char A1;
                A1 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(A1);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray10[] = new char[15];

            mm.getChars(0, 5, charArray10, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray10, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray10) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char A2;
                A2 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(A2);

            }
            System.out.println();

            char charArray11[] = new char[15];

            nn.getChars(0, 4, charArray11, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray11, 10);

            for (char ccharacter : charArray11) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char A3;
                A3 = ccharacter;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(A3);

            }
            System.out.println();

            ////////////////////// LEAP SECONDS ///////////////////////
            System.out.println("LEAP SECONDS");
            char charArray12[] = new char[3];

            qq.getChars(0, 2, charArray12, 0);
            replaceExpDesignator.replaceEwithD(charArray12, 0);

            for (char character : charArray12) {
                //System.out.println(character);
                char dtls;
                dtls = character;
                //System.out.println(alpha0);
                System.out.print(dtls);

            }
            System.out.println();

            break;
        }
    }

    public static void closeFile() {
        x.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please share your file as well ?

Comment: you can get it here                                                                               ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/data/daily/2017/304/17n/brdc3040.17n.Z